# Is it wrong to combine data in one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Say you need width and height in an editor app, is it wrong to have them as a string (JSON let's say) in a single column?

The string value is like the following:
{ width: 100, height: 100 }

Neither the width nor the height is displayed or edited separately in the UI, or to sort or filter by any of them.

Is it wrong, am I going too crazy with this and I should just have two separate columns?
Generally, is it a bad practice?

Comment: Violates [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form); I'd keep them separate in SQL Server, since it's not a NoSQL solution.

Comment: You're basically just adding an unnecessary limitation that could get super complex if you ever need to refactor it. Ideally you should be storing width and height separately as an integer and then appending 'px' or whatever unit after the data has been retrieved from the database. What if I want to see every object that's over 400 pixels tall? You have to select every single object then loop over them when you could just let sql do that "heavy lifting".

Comment: Plus, it's much easier to concatenate the values in your `SELECT` statement then it is to parse them. Just read through the SQL Server questions on here with people monkeying with patindex and custom functions trying to fix bad schema decision.

Comment: having had to work with a database that had rug dimensions set this way, and then having $bossLady decide she wanted to filter by either dimension....just put them as separate fields

Comment: It's not WRONG; it will work and if that's what makes the most sense for your app, do it. However, @roryap is correct, it's definitely bad practice and is not the best way to do it in most cases.  You never want to have to manipulate your data to make it usable.  If I wanted just the height, I would have to pull the value, parse it, separate it and then validate the value I got.  Lots of overhead that disappears if you store them in two separate columns.  Finally, that lets you keep the vals in their "native" form, which is numeric, instead of converting it to a completely different data type.

Comment: A good portion of SQL questions on this site are essentially forms of, "My database design violated first normal form, and now I'm having a ton of trouble querying my data."  It makes data very difficult to work with.

Comment: thank you all, but can you please see my reply to @roryap below please?

Comment: If I will eventually find I need them separated, I will separate them in columns, I don't see much of an issue with that. But my point is, right now, can't it be seen as a value which is a configuration string (which happens to be a resolution config of w x h)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's bad practice.  Let the database do what it's designed to do, which is to store raw data.  How you interpret or view that data is up to your application/report/etc.

Comment: 100% agree with idea that storage and view shouldn't be coupled, however I'm not so sure if this is my case too. I mean, would you agree that you can store data in one column which can be a JSON for example representing a configuration or something? Why can't it apply to my example too?

Comment: Well, sure you can store JSON in a data column.  Indeed, XML is often stored in a column.  But just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.  I know of lots of examples of development tools (I'm including DBMSs in that) that provide functionality that offends purists' sensibilities.  But ultimately, its up to you.  Just be thoughtful with your choices, because it's awfully hard to go back and refactor afterwards.

Comment: Take a XML layout configuration of an editor app. Having that as columns in a table just doesn't make sense at all. Heck, it might not even make sense to be in DB at all, might put it in a file instead, but given it's usually quite small, it's OK I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You think you don't need to filter now, but experience shows that eventually you will want to filter.  It is a bad practice to ever store multiple pieces of information in one field. That violates the first normal form of database design and is the simplest, most basic rule of database design.

Comment: The DB designer gets to decide what constitutes multiple pieces of information, not us, but in the long run if there's any possibility that it might not be atomic, then it's a good idea to break it up.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't *necessarily* violate first normal form any more than storing a street number and street name in the same attribute violates first normal form. The normal forms are rules based on rules that you impose on your data. Dr. Codd didn't know anything about your data when he invented the rules. If you 'promise' never to split up the field for any reason, then by your definition the field is atomic and you can achieve first normal form.

Comment: in theory correct, in practice....a pain in the butt

Comment: No, it's only a pain if the attribute is indeed not atomic. Otherwise it's correct to leave it alone.

Comment: And no matter how you slice this up the example posted here absolutely violates 1NF. There is no way around it. This is discussing two properties of an object in a single tuple. By definition that is two distinct values and should not be stored together.

Comment: @Sean,  Do you store birthday in three attributes?

Comment: No that is a single property, birthdate. The OP here clearly stated they are storing height and width. Your point about street number and street name don't work either. That is known as Address1 almost across the board.

Comment: You assert birthday is a single property: I can assert it's three properties. The point is that normalization must take into account the problem domain. You don't get to decide the atomicity of someone else's problem domain. If the OP says he will treat height and width together as atomic, then by definition he is in 1NF. You may be uncomfortable with his conceptualization but he owns the problem,  not us.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I have in mind too, but couldn't express so clearly.

Comment: I don't see much trouble if I later decide that I actually need that data separately (sorting just by width for example). Theoretically, I think the other way around would be more problematic, it would require more changes.

Comment: I gave this example in other replies: another way to see this is as a JSON/XML configuration. While width x height might look dubious to store in one field, what about a layout configuration of an editor app? I don't think anybody thinks even for a second to store that as separate columns, it's obvious it doesn't make sense, right? So why would a width x height config be bad to store in one column?

Answer (score 0):

yes it's wrong cause doing it will violate the **First Normal Form** which is

> the domain of each attribute contains only atomic (indivisible) values, and the value of each attribute contains only a single value from that domain.

Comment: The OP says he is atomic. He's in 1NF by definition.